# Does Not Override Abstract Method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) Error Despite Having Method

Tags: java, actionlistener

EDIT: Thanks to all who pointed out the typo! However, I am still having issues with my timer. For some reason, the timer is not causing the window to be repainted after every second. Edited code is posted below!

### I am having trouble compiling the following code- I get the two errors:

```
C:\java>javac Project2.java
Project2.java:8: error: Project2 is not abstract and does not override abstract
method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener
public class Project2 extends Applet implements ActionListener
       ^
Project2.java:19: error: <anonymous Project2$1> is not abstract and does not ove
rride abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener
        ActionListener getNewValues = new ActionListener() {
                                                           ^
2 errors
```

---

The purpose of the program is to simulate a race between a tortoise and a hare. A random number generator is used to determine how many moves forward or backward the tortoise and hare can move at any given turn.

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.lang.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color;



public class Project2 extends Applet
{
int squaret = 1;
int squareh = 1; //initial location of tortoise and hare
int move;
String tmessage;
String hmessage;

Timer timer;

public void init()
{

    timer = new Timer(1000, getNewValues); 
    timer.addActionListener(getNewValues);


}


ActionListener getNewValues = new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        repaint();
    }
};

public void paint (Graphics g) 
{
    move = (int)(Math.random() * 10) + 1;

    if (move > 8)
    {   
        squaret -= 6;
        tmessage = "Tortoise slips!";

        if (squaret < 1)
            squaret = 1;

    }       
    else if (move > 6)
    {
        squaret += 1;
        tmessage = "Tortoise plods slowly along.";
        if (squaret > 49)
            squaret = 50;

        squareh -=2;
        hmessage = "Hare slips slightly.";
        if (squareh < 1)
            squareh = 1;

    }

    else if (move > 5)
    {
        squaret += 1;
        tmessage = "Tortoise plods slowly along.";
        if (squaret > 49)
            squaret = 50;

        squareh -=12;
        hmessage = "Hare makes a big slip.";
        if (squareh < 1)
            squareh = 1;

    }

    else if (move > 2)
    {
        squaret += 3;
        tmessage = "Tortoise plods along quickly.";
        if (squaret > 49)
            squaret = 50;

        squareh += 1;
        hmessage = "Hare makes a small hop.";
        if (squareh > 49)
            squareh = 50;

    }
    else 
    {
        squaret += 3;
        tmessage = "Tortoise plods along quickly.";
        if (squaret > 49)
            squaret = 50;

        squareh += 9;
        hmessage = "Hare makes a big hop.";
        if (squareh > 49)
            squareh = 50;
    }

    g.drawString("Start (Square 1)", 0, 70);
    g.drawString("Finish (Square 50)", 900, 70);


    //determine positions for each area
    //each box is ten wide and 150 tall

    final int WIDTH_OF_OVAL = 4;
    final int HEIGHT_OF_OVAL = 4;
    final int WIDTH_OF_SQUARE = 20;
    final int HEIGHT_OF_SQUARE = 20;
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillOval(((WIDTH_OF_SQUARE - WIDTH_OF_OVAL) / 2) + WIDTH_OF_SQUARE * (squaret - 1), ((HEIGHT_OF_SQUARE - HEIGHT_OF_OVAL) / 2), WIDTH_OF_OVAL, HEIGHT_OF_OVAL);

    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    g.fillOval(((WIDTH_OF_SQUARE - WIDTH_OF_OVAL) / 2) + WIDTH_OF_SQUARE * (squaret - 1), ((HEIGHT_OF_SQUARE - HEIGHT_OF_OVAL) / 2) + HEIGHT_OF_SQUARE, WIDTH_OF_OVAL, HEIGHT_OF_OVAL);

    //show messages
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawString(tmessage, 10, 100);
    g.drawString(hmessage, 10, 120);

    g.drawLine(0, HEIGHT_OF_SQUARE, WIDTH_OF_SQUARE * 50, HEIGHT_OF_SQUARE); //draw horizontal middle line

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) //draw vertical lines
    {
        int width = (i + 1) * WIDTH_OF_SQUARE;

        g.drawLine(width, 0, width, HEIGHT_OF_SQUARE * 2);
    }

    if (squaret > 49 && squareh > 49)
    {
        g.drawString("Tie!", 500, 60);
        timer.stop();
    }   
    else if (squaret > 49)
    {
        g.drawString("Turtle wins!", 500, 60);
        timer.stop();
    }
    else if (squareh > 49)
    {
        g.drawString("Hare wins!", 500, 60);
        timer.stop();
    }   
    else
    {

    }   

    update(g);

}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    Project2 panel = new Project2();
    JFrame application = new JFrame();

    application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    application.add(panel);
    application.setSize(2600, 300);
    application.setVisible(true);

}
}
```

I have the method actionPerformed so I am not sure why I am getting the error that I am getting. Any feedback or help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `public void actionPeformed(ActionEvent e)` should be `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` (notice the **r**). It as a good idea to use `@Override` when overriding methods, your error would have been detected by the compiler.

Comment: Oh, thank you! I can't believe I didn't notice earlier :p Does the logic in the program look sound to you? I am very new to programming, so I'd love your input.

Comment: I'd use an IDE if I were you. Real-time 'spellcheck', compile check and auto-complete are your best friends!

Comment: As for your logic. I'd create a number of set activities (seems you have 3) and create an enum for that. Saves a lot of if/else stuff. It's also a better idea to split up code, like having a class or method specifically for moving, instead of placing it all in 1 file. And last but not least, your tortoise and a hare will probably do the same action every time. Can you figure out why? (I'll be back)

Comment: Joetjah: You're right about the tortoise and hare moving the same distance every time, but I have no clue why it is doing so. Also, when I compile it, I am unable to see the separate moves that the animals make- I am just left with the end result: both animals at the finish line and a message that says "Turtle wins", "Tie", etc. Maybe I am using my timer wrong? I was thinking that I should use a button instead of a timer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a spelling mistake in `actionPerformed`, you missed **r**. Change to:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  
{
     repaint();
}
```